# Azure Web app - angular I10n

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have uploaded my angular 4 web application in azure . In my local iis deployment there is no problem but in azure i have an error of missing locale-el.json and locale-en.json files. Files are not missing!!. I have tried to deploy my app with ftp and github with no success. Anoyone having similar problem in the past or know something about it?

here is my code declaring translation

```
export class SharedModule { constructor(public locale: LocaleService, public translation: TranslationService) {
this.locale.addConfiguration()
  .addLanguages(['en', 'el'])
  .setCookieExpiration(30)
  .defineLanguage('el');

this.translation.addConfiguration()
  .addProvider('./languages/locale-');

this.translation.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

i found out why ...

[How to serve static .json files from a Windows Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/)